# Split string on last desired character in bash

Tags: string, bash, split

I have a file named like this: `my-file-1.2.0.jar`

I want to extract the version of this file by splitting on the last `-`.
Hence I would have the following output: `1.2.0.jar`

I would also like to get rid of the .jar if it's possible with the same command to have this output: `1.2.0`

How can I achieve that with bash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```
#! /bin/bash
filename=my-file-1.2.0.jar
version=${filename##*-}
version=${version%.jar}
echo "$version"
```

`##` removes the largest matching pattern from the left. `%` removes the shortest matching pattern from the right (but `.jar` contains no wildcards, so using `%%` for the longest match would work equally well).

Answer (score 1):

Here is way to do this in single step using `extglob`:

```sh
shopt -s extglob
s='my-file-1.2.0.jar'
echo "${s//+(.jar|*-)}"

1.2.0
```